# Is an unnamed parameter actually passed during a function call?

Tags: c++, micro-optimization

```
template <typename TAG>
fn(int left, TAG, int right)
{
}

fn(0, some_type_tag(), 1);
/* or */
fn(0,int(), 1); // where the primitive, int, is not empty.
```

**EDIT:** There are two perspectives to this question.

1. Function declaration vs definition. The declaration might not name the parameter, but the declaration might do.This isn't the perspective of interest.
2. The template perspect, spectifically in meta-programming. The parameter In question is a tag used to pull out a meta-structure out of a trait. This is why the parameter is unnamed, I only care about the compile-time information - the type of the tag.

**/EDIT**

My tags are generally empty-structs, however in some parts of my code they are typedefs of primitive types.So, I'm interested to know if modern compilers will actually pass a parameter. This has two aspects.

1. Sizing the stack, taking into account the size of the unnamed parameter type.
2. Actually constructing the stack with the passed value.

Lets keep it to gcc 4.5 and msvc 2008+

Comment: Results will vary according to compilers and optimization levels. You will have to try it out.

Comment: I have 10 questions like this a day, if I experimented on everything I wouldn't get any work done ;), I've qualified the question with the two compilers I am interested in.

Comment: @Hassan: I think you'd have ended up before writing a simple test instead of writing the whole question :)

Comment: What about paramters passed in registers?

Comment: @diego, that might be true (but I doubt it), but even if it were, when I forgot the answer I wouldn't have a nice point of reference to return to in the future.

Comment: @Hassan GCC 4.5 uses different parameter passing styles depending on command line switches and the platform it compiles for.

Comment: @Hassan: if you forget the answer, it doesn't matter enough

Comment: @sehe it does matter sehe, I would be compelled to run the experiment again.... I don't memorize the gcc man page, neither do I memorize the Intel x86 assembly reference manual. Whilst I'm perfectly capable of conducting the experiment, I'm asking people who can answer this question of the top of their head.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite an interesting question actually.

First of all, note that we are in an imperative language, meaning that when you ask for something (even useless, such as constructing an unused object) then the compiler need to comply unless it can come up with an equivalent form. Basically, it could elide the parameter if it could prove that doing so would not change the meaning of the program.

When you write a function call, two things may happen (in the end):

- either it is inlined
- or a `call` is actually emitted

If it is *inlined*, then no parameter is passed, which effectively means that unused objects can be removed (and not even built) if the compiler can prove that the constructors and destructors involved do not perform any significant work. It works well for tags structures.

When a call is emitted, it is emitted with a specific calling convention. Each compiler has its own set of calling conventions which specify how to pass the various arguments (`this` pointer, etc...), generally trying to take advantage of the available registers.

Since only the declaration of the function is used to determine the calling convention (separate compilation model), then it is necessary to actually pass the object...

However, if we are talking about an empty structure, with no method and no state, then this is just some uninitialized memory. It should not cost much, but it does require stack space (at least, reserving it).

Demo using the llvm tryout:

```
struct tag {};

inline int useless(int i, tag) { return i; }

void use(tag);

int main() {
  use(tag());
  return useless(0, tag());
}
```

Gives:

```
%struct.tag = type <{ i8 }>

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  ; allocate space on the stack for `tag`
  %0 = alloca %struct.tag, align 8                ; <%struct.tag*> [#uses=2]

  ; get %0 address
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.tag* %0, i64 0, i32 0 ; <i8*> [#uses=1]

  ; 0 initialize the space used for %0
  store i8 0, i8* %1, align 8

  ; call the use function and pass %0 by value
  call void @_Z3use3tag(%struct.tag* byval %0)
  ret i32 0
}

declare void @_Z3use3tag(%struct.tag* byval)
```

Note:

- how the call to `useless` was removed, and no argument is build for it
- how to call to `use` cannot be removed, and therefore space is allocated for the temporary (I hope that the new versions don't 0-initialize the memory)

Comment: Just the right level of style,authority and tone I was looking for :D

Comment: @Hassan: I am learning as much as you are and I am known to have lapse of attention, so it is definitely authoritative ^^

Answer (score 12):

C++ has separate translation. Since the parameter can be named in the declaration but not in the function definition and vice versa, there's generally no way whether the compiler knows whether it's safe to omit the function argument. When it's all in the same translation unit, everything could be inlined and the argument name is entirely irrelevant to optimization.

**[Added]**

The seperate translation may not matter to this specific case, but a compiler builder that would add such an optimization must care. They're not going to put in such optimizations if it breaks perfectly valid code.

As for templates, it's necessary that the type of a template function is equal to the type of a non-template function, else it's impossible to take its address and assign it to a function pointer. Again, you have to take into account seperate translation. Just because you don't take the address of `foo<int>` in this TU doesn't mean you won't in another.

Comment: The compiler generates a function call if an address is taken. However, it won't (or shouldn't) use this new function unless it has to. that still leaves the class of function that is under scrutiny of my use-case =D. So perhaps we can assume that if an address is taken, the compiler creates a function call whist taking the tag parameter into account.

Comment: That still leaves a problem: if _one_ caller takes the parameter into account, the callee must, which in turn means that _all_ callers must.

Answer (score 7):

Whether the parameter is named or not has no effect on the function signature, and the compiler should pass it in. Consider that an unnamed parameter in the declaration of a function might be named in the definition.

Now, in the particular case of templates like the one above, chances are that the compiler will inline the code, in which case no arguments will be passed, and the unnamed argument will have no effect.

If what you are trying to do is tagging to resolve to different overloads, you can always fall back to a pointer, so that even if it is passed in, the cost will be minimal.

Comment: thanks I am indeed interested in the template perspective. I have qualified the question further to reflect this. Generally as I might use primitive types as tags, instead of empty structs, the size overhead shouldn't be that bad, if I use pointers I will pay the 8-byte overhead for 64-bit code at all times :D. Allthough 8-bytes of callstack space has practically no implications to performance I guess.

Comment: @Hassan Syed: If you use 64 bits, chances are that the calling convention makes extensive use of registers, which will in turn mean that for anything that fits the register the cost will be that of resetting it (in then non-inline case)

Comment: I can't really agree with the pointer argument, since an empty struct (sizeof 1) is smaller than a pointer (sizeof 4 or 8). Even the primitive type typedefs should be smaller.

Comment: @Xeo: fair enough. If you are to use empty structs, (or other small type) then a pointer will not provide any advantage, it would only be helpful if the object was of a bigger size, which is not the case being discussed and as such I should have kept myself quiet :)

Answer (score 2):

Good question, but you'll have to try on your compiler. In theory, if a parameter is not used, it doesn't have to be allocated in the stack. However, callers have to know how to call it, so my guess is that the element gets actually allocated in the stack.